# How to Run the copied sercidor symfony project in local machine

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm new to symfony framework and a new customer has a system developed over this framework. I do not particularly have problems with PHP for many years and I have difficulty learning to use the frameworks, symfony is not difernete.

However, I took the files to my server from the client machine and am having difficulty accessing the system address on my machine.

I'm getting an error accessing the address of the application.

---

Forbidden

### You don't have permission to access /project on this server.

Someone could still help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php symfony project:permissions
```

to fix permission problems on the project. If this does not work you can contact me (in portuguese)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the

```
allowoverride ALL
```

Directive inside the vhost, which block your .htaccess.

See config/vhostexample.txt for an example.